# Summarize a column according to each row's field and append the result to each row

Tags: python, pandas

I want to summarize a column according to each row's fields, and append that result to each row as a field (column).
For example, I want to count how many values of a column equal to each row's value of that column（'condition' column is just for simplification, it's actually a value calculated by using each row's fields.）:

Original dataframe:

```
    condition
0   True
1   False
2   True
3   True
4   False
5   True
6   True
```

result:

```
    condition   Count
0   True        5.0
1   False       2.0
2   True        5.0
3   True        5.0
4   False       2.0
5   True        5.0
6   True        5.0
```

I can only think of using `iterrows` to do this in an iterative way, although this is not a classic pandas way:

```
result = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index)

for i,r in df.iterrows():
    df2=df.loc[(df['condition']==r['condition'])]
    result.loc[i,'condition']=r['condition']
                                              
    result.loc[i,'Count']=df2.shape[0]  # How many items are the same as that row's 'condition' field
```

Is there any typical vectorization method to do this?
Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: `df['Count'] = df.groupby('Condition').transform('size')`

Comment: `df['count'] = df['condition'].apply(lambda x: df[df['condition']=x].count())`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) methods:

```
tally = df['condition'].value_counts()
df['Count'] = df['condition'].map(tally)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   condition  Count
0       True      5
1      False      2
2       True      5
3       True      5
4      False      2
5       True      5
6       True      5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the groupby method in pandas to summarize a column according to each row's fields. Here is an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'condition': [True, False, True, True, False, True, True]})
df['Count'] = df.groupby('condition')['condition'].transform('count')
```

This will give you the desired result:

```
   condition  Count
0      True      5
1     False      2
2      True      5
3      True      5
4     False      2
5      True      5
6      True      5
```